# Custom post type not recognized in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to create a simple ajax mechanism to refresh posts on my Wordpress blog.

When I call my custom php file I do:

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`

to recognize the Wordpress functions.

However, when I call my WP_query function, it doesn't recognize my custom post type. Any idea why?

My arguments:

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'custom-post-type', 
   'posts_per_page' => 5, 
   'order' => 'DESC' 
   );
```

When removing post_type it works.

Comment: Is your custom post type actually called 'custom-post-type'? Otherwise, this should be the same as the string you used in the first argument of `register_post_type()`.

Comment: It's not, it's just for demonstration purposes.. the custom post type is the exact same word as registered